# Why are Julia benchmarks not shown in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, benchmarking

Hi Below is some simple code that displays the benchmark results form a Julia REPL. In VSCode I have tried

1. launching the Julia REPL from the Command Pallet and Running the file without  Debugging
2. Execute the active File in Repl from the drop down menu top right

In both cases the println statements are displayed but  not the benchmark results. Is this to be expected or have I messed up?

```
using DifferentialEquations, BenchmarkTools
A = rand(1000,1000); B = rand(1000,1000); C = rand(1000,1000)
println("TX 1 and 2")
test(A,B,C) = A + B + C
@benchmark test(A,B,C)
println("T 1 End")

t(A,B,C) = A .+ B .+ C
@benchmark t(A,B,C)
println("TX 2 End")
readline()
println("After read")
```

I found a workaround : remove or comment out the @benchmark from the file and
run them directly in the REPL.

Answer (score 1):

This should depend on which setting you have for result type (Julia > Execution: Result Type in the Settings GUI or `julia.execution.resultType` in settings.json).

With "inline" result type I get:

[image]

Hovering over the `BenchmarkTools.Trial` box, I get:

[image]

Note the `println` line just shows a tick as it has been executed but didn't return anything, instead it printed to the REPL, the terminal at the bottom now looks like this:

[image]